# 1/r attractive force by cellular automaton

Tags: simulation, cellular-automata

Does there exist a cellular automaton (in 2D) which simulates a $1/r$ force between particles?

More specifically, I would like to know whether it is possible, with strictly local update rules, to have two objects (defined within the model) attract each other with a $1/r$ force, where $r$ is the distance separating the objects.  This would in particular entail an acceleration of the object (particles) as they get closer together.

More generally, can long range attractive forces between objects (blobs) be simulated in a cellular automaton setting with strictly local rules?

Comment: How do you encode the distance and the object?  If the rules are strictly local, i.e., around one object, how would you know which way an object should be attracted?

Comment: Indeed, this is precisely what makes the problem non-trivial. I would naively expect that if  solution exists, then it would be of the following form: a 2d lattice which can be populated by "particles", superposed with an 'ether' which would send out 'signals' in all directions when a particle is present and do nothing otherwise. When a signal reaches another "particle" then it tells the particle to move in the direction of the sent out signal. Somehow the signals should also have some memory otherwise there would be an excess accumulation of them for distant particles...

Comment: But whether this actually acts as a long-range force, moreover one depending on the distance, is not clear to me. I was wondering whether this question has already been considered?

Comment: imho extremely deep/significant open research question crosscutting key disciplines such as TCS,QM,(particle) physics,emergent behavior, etc. suggest migrate/promote this to cstheory.se

Comment: re MJKs idea about attraction via "signals". another basic physical model for particle attraction is overall _density_ of a field. so imagine you have a large pool with a density gradient, and constant density particles in this pool. the particles will move/drift from regions of higher density to lower density. ie "float" in a way. this may be a unified theory of both attraction and gravitation that even the [standard model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) hasnt really unified yet and is largely a key open question in physics.

Answer (score 3):

If by "simulate" you mean something like "generate a picture of what the dynamics would be under such a force," then the answer to your question is *yes*: there exist [universal cellular automata](http://www.complex-systems.com/abstracts/v15_i01_a01.html) (including Conway's original [Game of Life rule set](http://rendell-attic.org/gol/utm/index.htm)).

If, however, you're asking about whether our universe can be explained in terms of strictly local update rules, then your question is still open.  [Konrad Zuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_Space) was one of the first to explore this question explicitly in terms of CA; see [Wolfram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_New_Kind_of_Science), [Schmidhuber](http://www.idsia.ch/~juergen/everything/html.html), or [t'Hooft](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/gthpub/digit01.pdf) for more recent work.

Comment: +1 For a really beautiful answer. It demonstrates that what the OP is asking is definitely possible, without giving any hint of an indication as to how such a thing might be accomplished. Well, the hint's there, but following it to completion would be about the most tedious thing I could possibly imagine.

Comment: I suppose Paul Gordan would say, ["Das ist nicht Mathematik. Das ist Theologie!"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hilbert#Hilbert_solves_Gordan.27s_Problem), but even theology has its merits!

Comment: +1 clever idea but think this should be sketched out a little more. guess it assumes that "attraction", particles, etc are based on algorithms that generate or simulate them.

Comment: I suppose it hinges on the definition of what it means "to simulate."  I suspect the OP was looking for a CA rule set such that "live" cells (or some configuration thereof) are "attracted" to each other with a 1/r force. I suspect this is possible, but tedious to construct and largely irrelevant.  I stand by my original answer since an analogous observation could be applied to any computer simulation - after all, strings of 1's and 0's in a processor pipeline don't "look" much like n-bodies interacting in a gravitational field, yet we accept that as a "simulation."

Comment: sorry, think you're handwaving there. further thought. actually what is needed more is a construction like "screen completeness" rather than Turing completeness (they are not really the same thing). in "screen completeness" one would have to show that one can create a 2d grid/screen and turn on pixels arbitrarily on the screen. Turing completeness alone is not enough to demonstrate that (note eg Turing completeness could be demonstrated on a 1d tape, but conceivably fail to create arbitrary patterns on a 2d screen). in this case the model is a "screen". (maybe other non 2-d models are ok.)

Comment: I'm not sure I agree/understand. Can you elaborate on why Turing completeness does not imply "screen completeness?"  Also, can you clarify what it means to "create a 2d grid/screen"?  I'm interpreting a "screen" as an output device - that is, some finite, fixed implementation with no processing power of its own, such that what's displayed on the screen is a function of the symbols on the TM's output tape.

Comment: @rphv: Turing completeness doesn't mean that you can find a CA so that information travels faster than the speed of light, even though Turing machines can easily simulate CA where information travels faster than the speed of light. Here, if the OP wants a CA such that objects are attracted with $1/r$ force which runs at some constant slowdown, Turing completeness does not give you that. If you want a machine which, every so often, displays a picture of what the dynamics would be under such a force, Turing completeness will give you that.

Comment: "screen completeness": there exists a TM that can create arbitrary graphics given a screen device that accepts coordinates (eg encoded as binary) as input, hooked up to the TM. but for CAs, the computation takes place on the "screen", there is no natural decoupling of the computation and the screen.

Answer (score 1):

this is a very significant research question & there is a more general question here that is studied by some. the deeper question is "to what degree can CA(-like) rules reproduce the laws of physics". the larger question is a very important open question with large amounts of speculation and research on the subject, but unfortunately conventional scientific/physics wisdom considers it a more fringe area of modern physics. my understanding is that your specific question is basically open also.

regarding your question in a more general way, here are links on many closely related themes, having researched this thread/area recently:

- research into the game of [Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life) (which has been proven [Turing complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394957/why-can-conways-game-of-life-be-classified-as-a-universal-machine) by Conway and others) is highly relevant. "gliders" would seem to exhibit laws of attraction to some degree, but the topic and analysis can be subtle. suppose two glider guns are pointing to each other, are the gliders "attracting" each other?
- ['t Hooft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerard_'t_Hooft), Nobel prize winning physicist has investigated in several papers the general question/theme of whether local discrete laws can reproduce QM dynamics or other low-level laws of physics eg in this paper, [Relating the quantum mechanics of discrete systems to standard canonical quantum mechanics](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.4926)
- an example of opinion on 't Hoofts directions (being considered fringe), see [’t Hooft on Cellular Automata and String Theory](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/wordpress/?p=5022) by Woit, a theoretical physicist/String theorist expert/skeptic
- [Fredkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredkin) speculated long ago on ["Digital physics"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_physics) and some of this has been expanded on by [Wolfram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_wolfram) eg in [New Kind of Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_kind_of_science).
- a key angle: 2d/3d [solitons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton) seem to be able to be generated from purely local "rules" ie local differential equations, and therefore it seems solid/likely that CAs exist that replicate those same differential equations, although this appears to be yet to be demonstrated. solitons are known to have many strong resemblances to particle/atomic interations including attraction/repulsion aspects/properties. see eg
  [Solitons & cellular automata](http://vzn1.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/solitons-cellular-automata-quantum-mechanics-and-disagreeing-with-scott-aaronson/)
- recent breakthrough analytical/theoretical work by Brady shows that a soliton-like system called *sonons* has strong analogues to basic physics such as particle, electromagnetic/quantum analogies. [The irrotational motion of a compressible inviscid fluid.](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rmb4/sonons/sonon.pdf)
- a new site dedicated to the subject of [classical fluid particle physics](http://classicalfluidparticlephysics.tumblr.com/) with references to Bradys work, tying it in with physics phenomena, eg [summary to classical fluid dynamics theory](http://classicalfluidparticlephysics.tumblr.com/post/50252335055/summary-classical-fluid-theory)